# Testing for Normality and displaying combined results for multiple columns in a dataframe (R)

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine two plots (ggqplot and ggdensity) and include the p value from the output the shapiro test for multiple columns of a dataframe.

Input - dataframe (df)
list of columns interested in - "varlist"

I've extracted the names of the columns I want to extract with (example) `varlist <- names(df[c(10:20)]` I want to Loop? or use another method to produce an output of the qqplot, ggdensity and P value for the shapiro test all displayed together.

```
library(ggpubr)

ggqplot(df$i)
ggdensity(df$i)
shapiro.test(df$i)
```

This would be useful for others looking to quickly get all of these measures on their data. I've looked but cannot find how to piece it together. I'm thinking a function that makes each graph and combines the information then pass the i from varlist through it?

I've extracted this function from a previous answer which quickly gets shapiro test results - this may be helpful?

```
myfun <- function(x, group) {
  data.frame(x, group) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(
      statistic = ifelse(sd(x)!=0,shapiro.test(x)$statistic,NA), 
      p.value = ifelse(sd(x)!=0,shapiro.test(x)$p.value,NA)
    )
}
```